# VS2013 compilation for WinXP, procedure entry point could not be located

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I had a working `VS2010` C++ solution, output of which I could launch on XP and Win7 with no problems.

Now I switched to VS2013 and imported the project. From that moment on, the output exe could be launched only on Win7. On XP it would give me "`Error Executing Program! (5)`".

Well I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724029/windows-xp-and-windows-server-2003-support-in-visual-studio-2013%20and%20I%20set%20the%20Platform%20toolset%20to%20v120_xp)

Since then the error I get while launching the application on XP is "`The procedure entry point K32GetModuleFilenameExA could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll`"

Does it mean I also use some `dll`, that is not compiled with `v120_xp`, or is it something else?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307170/build-allegro-5-for-windows-xp).

The problem is that the dynamic library has to be compiled with *v120_xp* as well.